# How can I get Access_Token from Flurl

Tags: azure, owin, azure-api-apps, flurl

I'm developing an app, I have a backend server `Azure API` App that uses `Owin Token Bearer`. I'm trying to Login to my backend and get token back like in my web client. I can login in successfully but there is no token in the response message. I have this code

```
 string _url = ServerPath.Path + "/token";
 HttpResponseMessage message = await _url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(
     new {
         UserName = Username,
         Password = Password,
         grant_type = "password"
     }
);
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try lower-case `username` and `password` per the spec. It or may not matter, depending on how forgiving the server app is. If that doesn't work, please elaborate on what you mean by "I can login successfully". Do you mean this call returns a 200 with and empty body? That sounds like a bug on the server side.

Comment: it return response message which shows i have successful login, what im looking for its my token in that response message... i cant find the token return in the response message

Comment: If you do `.ReceiveString()` at the end of your call you'll get the response body back as a string. If you still don't see a token, I think there's a problem on the server side.

Comment: Thanks @Todd Menier. .RecieveString() worked.

Comment: Excellent. There's a cleaner way, I'll provide it in an answer..

Answer (score 1):

The authentication method you're using returns a standard [OAuth 2.0 token response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.4). The token is in the `HttpResponseMessage` you're getting back, and Flurl's `ReceiveJson` can help you pluck it out:

```
var response = await _url
    .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new
    {
        UserName = Username,
        Password = Password,
        grant_type = "password"
    })
    .ReceiveJson();

var token = (string)response.access_token;
```

Note that I used the non-generic version of `ReceiveJson` here, which returns a `dynamic`. You could make this a little more robust by creating a class (call it `TokenResponse`) matching the JSON structure of the entire response body, use `ReceiveJson<TokenResponse>()`, and have a strongly typed response object to pluck `access_token` out of.